# How would you implement a simple method of aggregation in Unity 2D C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, aggregation, composition

I am making a game and I need to have aggregation/composition in my code. Can someone explain how it works in unity and give a simple mini example. I might have it already but I am not sure

```
public class Card : Monobehaviour {

}

public class SpawnCard {
    public Card newCard;
}
```

I am confused as to whether It is similar to normal (ConsoleApp) C# or different

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to clarify your question and what you're trying to accomplish. If you're referring to the general concept of "object composition", then yes, your `SpawnCard` class containing an instance of `Card` technically meets that definition. However, it's unclear how useful that would be, or what `Card` or `SpawnCard` mean in this context.

Comment: I am trying to accomplish composition because the teacher said so .I was just showing a brief example because i was unclear as to if it is similar to ConsoleApp.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Composition is used to combine behaviors of several classes. What kind of combined behaviors do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Try explaining what you are trying to do in Plain English instead of using vague technical buzzwords like "aggregation" and "composition".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregation / composition / object association works in two ways in Unity and choosing which method to use requires careful thought.

There is aggregation by source-code operation (ie ObjectA does a Find<>() operation in runtime and locates ObjectB)

There is Unity build-time GUI aggregation (where you expose a public field in ObjectA and drag-drop a scene instance of ObjectB into the inspector property of ObjectA).

Choosing the correct balance requires trial and effort.  Tight coupling can occur if you use the first approach OR the second approach.  You can potentially offload the association logic into an expert class - that way neither ObjectA or ObjectB types have to know the association logic and thus they don't get polluted with code that is not consistent with their defined purposes.

Good Luck!